# PHPMyAdmin expired session right after login

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Right after login, soon as I click on any option, `PHPMyAdmin` exists with the message:

> "Your session has expired. Please log in again."

I havent made any changes or updates in the server and already tried restarting the server and the problem continues.

What may be causing this?

Comment: most likely, the storage of your session does not work properly. If it's tmp-dir based, maybe something is deleting the PHP session files? If you're in a load balancing cluster, make sure the session storage is replicated across all instances. First check your PHP configuration on how session information is stored, and then check this store. Also, the local server time may be incorrect in a virtual environment. Check if the clock ticks normally.

Comment: *"What may be causing this?"* - No idea; it could be anything and the question is short on code and detail.

Comment: *"PHPMyAdmin expired session right after login"* - what does phpmyadmin have to do with sessions and php? This isn't a php question; it's a serverfault issue.